# How to handle a specific foreign key error in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have following table structure:

users:

```
id INT(10)
```

posts:

```
id INT(10)
```

users_posts:

```
user_id (FOREIGN KEY [fk_up_1]: users.id)
post_id (FOREIGN KEY [fk_up_2]: posts.id)
```

Then, I create a procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_user_add_post(v_user_id INT(10), v_post_id INT(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1452 RESIGNAL SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Invalid user_id or post_id";
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION RESIGNAL;

    INSERT INTO `users_posts` (`user_id`, `post_id`)
        VALUES (v_user_id, v_post_id);
END
```

**The question:** how can I differentiate between specific FK error conditions? Can I retrieve a name of FK that errored (`fk_up_1` and `fk_up_2` in my example above)? For instance, I might want to log an error somewhere if invalid user_id is passed, so it can come in handy.

Comment: FKs should be internal system values, or lookups of external data, so why would they ever be wrong?

Comment: @MitchWheat: If I executed this: `CALL sp_user_add_post(111, 222)`, and ID 111 does not exist in users table, an error 1452 would be thrown with message: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (details)". FK itself would not error just like that, that's not what I meant.

Comment: which version of MySQL are you running? If it is 5.6.4 or above then you could make use of GET DIAGNOSTICS and return the error message as a procedure output variable?

Comment: @TomMac: Still running 5.5 I'm afraid.. But, it's a start. Why don't you post it as an answer (with usage example if possible), so I can mark it as answer if nothing better comes up?